# How to get url request parameter from inside LIferay/IceFaces/JSF portlet backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, liferay, portlet, icefaces

Is posible for a portlet to read a request parameter of its surrounding page?

E.g. the URL of the page the portlet resides in is http://example.com/mygroup/mypage?foo=bar Is it possible to read the "foo" parameter from a portlet that is on that page?

Portlet Container is Liferay 6.0.5.

P.S.

I have already tried:

```
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest((javax.portlet.PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest())).getParameter("foo")
```

but I always get null for productId

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`ExternalContext.getRequestParameterMap()`

Comment: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("foo") returns NULL for me.

Comment: If it helps, I am doing this from a partialSubmit="True" icefaces commandbutton. So an ajax call is involved...

Comment: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("foo") also returns NULL

Comment: Are you able to debug this app? If so, you may have to inpect `ExternalContext.getRequest()` and follow its properties until you get to an internal request that has the parameters.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest((javax.portlet.PortletRequest) javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest())).getParameter("foo") will return a value on initial page load. But if I press a icefaces commandbutton I lose the ability to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do the trick:

```
javax.portlet.PortletRequest pr = (javax.portlet.PortletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("javax.portlet.request");
java.lang.reflect.Method method = pr.getClass().getMethod("getOriginalHttpServletRequest");
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)method.invoke(pr, new Object[] {});
return httpServletRequest.getParameter(YOUR_PARAM_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a partial submit, the icefaces ajax bridge (which replaces a usual jsf portlet bridge) is avoiding the normal portal action/render request, contacting directly the blocking servlet (in order to avoid invalidating other request-scoped portlets and in general, to be faster). Because of this, all those params/attributes which are set in a normal portal request are not set in ajax. They are set only in the initial GET type request for that page. So, actually what you should do is saving those params in the @PostConstruct or some other method of your controlling bean, and then reuse them later. (They wouldn't change in a partial submit anyway, right?).
Keep in mind though, that this will not work if you use IceFaces in conjuction with Spring (and their EL Resolver, since that eliminates your extended request scope).

Answer (score -1):

if you are in JSF environment then try this:

```
String param = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance().getRequestQueryStringParameter("foo");
```